# App Registrations: Deletion of permissions is not reflected in API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have access to my Azure AD Portal. I also have an external ASP.NET application which is accessing the Microsoft Graph API. For this purpose I add an App Registration which give me an Application ID and Key to be able to configure my ASP.NET application to authenticate itself against the Graph API.

I need the my ASP.NET application to read groups out of Azure AD. I can authenticate successfully but I get an error saying that I have not enough privileges. Then I go back to the Azure Ad Portal and add permissions to the App Registration I added. This works ok so in the end I have the Graph API response on my ASP.NET application.

Now it comes the issue. I selected too many permissions so I want to use the smallest set of permissions that are necessary for my ASP. So I go the Azure Portal AD again and remove some of the permissions. When I test my app again, I still receive the groups even if I have no permissions selected.

I think this is an issue. Or there's some kind of delay? I don't think so because when the API is working and has the proper permissions I can add a group in Azure AD Portal and instantly see it in my ASP.NET application.

This issue is specially annoying because you can't really test the permissions your app needs.

Thanks.

[image: Azure Ad Portal - Permissions Blade]

Comment: Did you click `Grant permissions` again?

Comment: If what Joy said doesn't work, then you might need to go manually delete the AppRoleAssignments from the service principal via MS Graph API explorer / Azure AD PowerShell

Comment: Granting permissions didn't do any difference. @juunas will check into that, but do you know why the issue is happening? Shouldn't the permissions be updated automatically?

Comment: No, permissions granted to a service principal do not change if you change required permissions in the Application object. Grant permissions might be just ensuring the necessary grants exist and not cleaning up unnecessary ones.

Comment: @juunas thanks for the clarification. Do you have any reference for that information? In your first comment you propose to 'manually delete the AppRoleAssignments from the service principal via MS Graph API explorer. Could you please elaborate a little bit more this approach or link some reference?

Comment: Here's the docs for that particular action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-delete?view=graph-rest-beta. You can also use Azure AD Graph API for this (if you want a stable endpoint, as MS Graph API has these still in beta), or you can use Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets.